# How can I sum input fields by name starting with?

Tags: jquery

What I would like to achieve is using this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("input[name^='audi']").css("background-color", "yellow");});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input name="audi_a4" type="text" value="3">
        <input name="audi_a6" type="text" value="4">
        <input name="mercedes" type="text" value="5">
        <input name="toyota" type="text" value="2">
        <p>
            This selector selects all input fields with the attribute name that starts with 'audi'.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Rather than selecting inputs I would like to get a sum of them in another input field (Here the sum should be "7". How can I do this?

Comment: Is it possible to modify the HTML at all? It would be much easier to achieve this if you can group the input  element by class or data attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use name attribute to sum them. In example above this is used to change css formatting. I believe it can be done to achieve sum of fields.

Comment: Are the number of inputs dynamic, or is there always only `audi`, `mercedes` and `toyota`?

Comment: form is not dynamic. it is always as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    updatesum();
  });
  
  function updatesum(){
    sum=0;
    $("input[name^='audi']").each(function(){
      sum+=Number($(this).val());
    });
    $("#sumofaudi").val(sum);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input name="audi_a4" type="text" value="3" onchange="updatesum();">
<input name="audi_a6" type="text" value="4" onchange="updatesum();">
  SUM of AUDI :<input name="sumofaudi" id="sumofaudi" type="text" value="">
<input name="mercedes" type="text" value="5" onchange="updatesum();">
<input name="toyota" type="text" value="2" onchange="updatesum();">
  

<p>This selector selects all input fields with the attribute name that starts with 'audi'.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is nearly what I was looking for. How to make this to calculate as I type? Now it is working only for predefined values in html form

Comment: now i update onchange of any text box update answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 iTotal = 0;
        $("input[name^='audi']").each(function () {
            iTotal += parseInt($(this).val(),10);
        });
        alert(iTotal)
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to complement it with context, detailed information and/or code examples. The _Post Answer_ button should be used only for **complete answers to the question**.